# I have core js and core js pure in my bundle. Is this right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle

I am currently using webpack to bundle my project and my main.js is pretty big so I currently looking for a way to reduce size of my main.js.
I can see the of the the biggest things in my bundles is core-js stuff.
I am using core-js to support IE11 mainly for promise and generator(Saga)

I have some setup on babelrc.

```
["@babel/preset-env", {
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "corejs": 3,
      "targets": {
        "ie": "11"
      }
}]

["@babel/transform-runtime", {
      "corejs": 3
}],
```

**index.js**

```
import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
```

I like to know if both of them should be in the bundle or one of each.

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/848

Answer (score 0):

Your babel setting is incorrect. You can't set `"@babel/preset-env"` and `"@babel/transform-runtime"` to both use corejs 3.

The core-js author said [these](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/848)

> It's 3 different ways of core-js usage. You should use only one of
> them:
>
> 1. core-js direct import
> 2. core-js injecting by usage plugin from
>    @babel/preset-env
> 3. core-js injecting without global pollution by
>    @babel/transform-runtime plugin

I also learned that the hard way thought this [How do I polyfill Promise.any() using babel 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088525/how-do-i-polyfill-promise-any-using-babel-7)

The key question here is what is the difference between core-js and core-js-pure ? As the author said it in the core-js 3 [release note](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/pull/325),

> Extract a version without global namespace pollution to a separate
> core-js-pure package (replacement for core-js/library).

Check the `core-js-pure` [readme](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js-pure/README.md) for further information (like "The pure version of core-js / babel-runtime is intended for usage in libraries' code ...").

In your case because you set them both, core-js & core-js-pure both imported into main.js, so it is big.