# How do I polyfill Promise.any() using babel 7?

Tags: webpack, async-await, babeljs, es6-promise, babel-polyfill

I use webpack to bundle my codes for my clients. According to my question here [Is it possible to break away from await Promise.all when any promise has fulfilled (Chrome 80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66044132/is-it-possible-to-break-away-from-await-promise-all-when-any-promise-has-fulfill) I want to use `Promise.any()` but `Promise.any` is only available for Chrome85+ and my clients need me to support Chrome 80+. Naturally I had thought with babel I can polyfill `Promise.any()`, e.g. corejs provides [Promise.any](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.promise.any.js). But I don't know what I did wrong, now with Babel 7 polyfill I can't even make Promise.any work for Chrome85+!

Following is what I have done,

First, my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js'
        ui:'./src/ui/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        libraryExport: 'default',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        library: '[name]'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
   ...
}
```

I initially used Babel 6. With Babel 6 I can verify the code (using Promise.any) bundled by webpack works for Chrome 85+ (probably it didn't polyfill Promise.any at all).

I then upgrade Babel 6 to Babel 7, using `npx babel-upgrade --write`and with some twists (e.g. `"useBuiltIns": 'usage'`). webpack can bundle my code then, but to my surprise the bundled code with `Promise.any()` can't even work on Chrome85+. I got the error message "**Uncaught (in promise) rejected**"

The following is my babelrc

```
{
    "env": {
        "production": {
            "presets": [
                [
                    "@babel/preset-env",
                    {
                        "targets": {
                            "browsers": [
                                "last 4 Chrome versions",
                                "last 3 Firefox versions",
                            ]
                        },
                        "modules": "commonjs",
                        "debug": true,
                        "useBuiltIns": 'usage'
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                    {
                        "corejs": 2,
                        "regenerator": true
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/908) against core-js and the author told me I should not use core-js@2. With that pointer I finally made it work with core-js@3!

Following is my `.babelrc`. The main point is to set **corejs3** either in "presets" or in "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" , **but not both.** Making babel work is so hard that I list my .babelrc here and I am not sure I have set everything right.

```
"production": {
            "presets": [
                [
                    "@babel/preset-env",
                    {
                        "targets": { ... },
                        "modules": "commonjs",
                        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                        "corejs": {
                            "version": 3, 
                            "proposals": true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                    {
                        "regenerator": true
                        //or don't useBuiltIns but here
                        // "corejs": {
                        //     "version": 3,
                        //     "proposals": true
                        // }
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
```

With this setting I can see the webpack output like and polyfill finally works!

```
Added following core-js polyfills:
  esnext.aggregate-error { "chrome":"78", "ie":"10", "safari":"13.1" }
  esnext.promise.any { "chrome":"78", "ie":"10", "safari":"13.1" }
  ...
```